# .ipynb file is not updating when I make changes in jupyter

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

For some reason, when I'm editing my code in jupyter, the corresponding ipynb file is not registering any changes. I added a bunch of markdown explaining my code, and even edited some of the code frames, but running a git status indicates that my ipynb file is not changing at all. Why is this the case? Is there some other way to log jupyter notebook changes to git?

for now my workaround is to download my new code as an ipynb and just replace the old one, but I'm curious what I'm missing here.

Comment: Are you saving it?

Comment: Jupyter will auto-save at some interval. But you can manually save it. That will write to file and you will see the changes with Git.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in PyCharm `2023.2.1`.

I saved the `.ipynb` file, but the changes were not reflected in git. Restarting the kernel made no difference. I tried closing and re-opening the file, and my changes were still visible, but still not in git. The notebook otherwise seemed to be working normally.

Then I terminated the Jupyter Server by quitting PyCharm.  When I re-opened it my changes were lost, but from that point on changes were reflected in git as normal.

I don't know what was going on here, or how it got into this state.

**Edit**

I subsequently found this issue again, and did `File` -> `Invalidate Caches...`, which worked.  This is an incredibly annoying issue. I don't know why PyCharm has caches that prevent it writing edits to disk.

Answer (score 0):

In general, both autosaving and using the "Save and Checkpoint" option should work.

The most likely issue is that you have `ipynb` in your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably open your file using Jupyter Notebook/Lab (JN/L) sidebar menu where simultaneously JN/L is opened from Anaconda. Files opened and saved in this way are typically located in your User directory what is default set up when installing Anaconda. So not in your git project thats why you must copy it. To fix that you should open Jupyter Lab/Notebook directly from "main" git directory. So open PythonShell, goto main project directory (e.g. cd /myProject/...) and run command "Jupyter Lab". From now on your JN/L sidebar you will see only files located in git project and every changes made in .ipynb files should be visible in your git project as modified aftet git status command.